# Load Font Awesome manually in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, font-awesome

I am fairly new to Wordpress. I am trying to add a Font Awesome to the "list" of my wp_enqueue style sheets. When I add it by using the CDN link, it works perfectly. However, when I add the stylesheet manually, it shows boxes around the area where the icon should be (as if there is nothing or hasn't been added).

Here is my current code which is NOT working

```html
wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```

Below is the code that does work.

```html
 wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```

How do I go about linking or calling the Font Awesome stylesheet that is in my CSS folder? I have added actions on my side, My only issue is getting the FA stylesheet to work manually.

Comment: First, I advise you to use the CDN; FA is used on so many sites that users will likely already have it cached thus giving your users a faster site load. Did you follow the steps here? http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

Comment: What is your output for `get_template_directory_uri()`

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? If not, are you building your own theme from scratch or are you building a child theme?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add fonts directory.which contain fonts file used by the font-awesome.min.css file.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that you are working on a child theme. You are calling the 'parent theme' directory when enqueuing the font-awesome. Try to use 
`wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css');`

More info https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri

Also check the path to the CSS by puting it in the browser, ie `http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/font-awesome.min.css`

Answer (score -2):

Here's how I did it:

In the `header.php` file (or where-ever you keep your header code,) copy and paste this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

This is a whole lot better than fiddling with PHP. Another way is to install a Font Awesome plugin for WordPress, which does work. Just go to the Plugins area and search for "font awesome." Click the Easy FontAwesome plugin, install it, activate it and you're done!

Comment: I'm sorry Calum, but I must disagree with your advice. Yes, it is a possible answer. Yes, it might seem easier and more straight forward. BUT you are not taking in account other scripts (ie plugins, etc.), that might be trying to load the same resources and they have no way of knowing that FontAwesome is already loaded if it is done your way. That's why WP has a queue for scripts and styles, where you can even set the dependencies – ie. don't load this until that has been loaded. I marked it down, because in terms of Wordpress your answer is bad practice.